# Is it possible to customize VS Code autocomplete menu?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to make VS Code autocomplete menu look like Atom autocomplete menu. Is there an addon available for this or is it even possible to make such a thing?

Comment: Can you show us how you want it to look like?

Answer (score -1):

See if this can help you [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#:~:text=You%20can%20trigger%20IntelliSense%20in,in%20JavaScript](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#:%7E:text=You%20can%20trigger%20IntelliSense%20in,in%20JavaScript) IntelliSense to VSCode.